# Execute remote ssh command "which java" (JSch java)

Tags: java, unix, ssh, jsch, remotecommand

I'm trying to execute command `which java` remotely via ssh (JSch java).

I have a remote host that when I execute the command `which java` directly in the shell the output is like "/ltm/rt/oracle/java/jdk1.8/bin/java" that is correct, but when I try to execute the same command remotely via JSch java the output from the server is empty and I have the following error: **which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin)**

The user I've used for the authentication over ssh is the same that I use to access to the machine directly.

I'm asking for some ideas to bypass this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Hi @f1sh, the code is simple, I want only to execute "which java" remotely, but the ouput is empty:

WHICH_JAVA=`which java`
echo $WHICH_JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the pseudo-terminal mode the command is executed correctly.